# Repeat items in a column as many times as corresponding number in another column

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file

```
A 3
B 5
C 1
D 2
```

I want to output items in column 1 as many times as the corresponding value in column 2, as in

```
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
C
D
D
```

I have split my file in two lists chr and pos

```
chr=(A B C D)
pos=(3 5 1 2)
```

and used

```
for i in ${chr[@]}; do for j in $(seq ${pos[@]}); do echo "${i}"; done; done
```

but I get the result, where each item in chr is repeated as many times as the first in pos

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
D
D
D
```

It would be better if I didn't split the file as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using a simple `awk`:

```
awk 'NF == 2{for (i=1; i<=$2; i++) print $1}' file
```

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
C
D
D
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your script is `j in $(seq ${pos[@]})`. Here, `pos[@]` lists *all* numbers from the second column. To fix the problem, only the number from the current row has to be used. Right now, this is not possible as you would need the current line number `ln` in order to access `pos[ln]`. You can change the first loop to `for ln in "${!chr[@]}"` and replace all `i` by `${chr[ln]}`. However, there are better solutions.

#### Alternative Solution Without Splitting In Advance

```
while read -r value repeat; do
    yes "$value" | head -n "$repeat";
done < inputFile
```

or (if the values don't contain special symbols)

```
xargs -n2 sh -c 'yes "$0" | head -n "$1"' < inputFile
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="something.txt"

while read -r char count
do
    for ((i=0; $i<$count; i++))
    do
        echo $char
    done
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably pull the indices from the `chr[]` array and then use the index for the desired results.

First we'll look at what the arrays look like:

```
$ typeset -p chr
declare -a chr=([0]="A" [1]="B" [2]="C" [3]="D")
$ typeset -p pos
declare -a pos=([0]="3" [1]="5" [2]="1" [3]="2")
```

As you can tell from the other answers there are several ways to generate the desired output; for a solution where we stick with the two arrays, I'd modify the original code like such:

```
for i in ${!chr[@]}                        # loop through the chr[] array indices
do
    for (( j=0; j<"${pos[${i}]}"; j++ ))   # replace seq with a for loop/counter
    do
        echo "${chr[${i}]}"                # display our chr[] array value
    done
done

A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
C
D
D
```